# Can I refactor my error handling for an if statement if the else clause also raises an error?

Tags: python, exception, refactoring

Currently my code looks like this:

```
if cond1:
  try:
    f1()
  except ValueError:
    # handle error
elif cond2:
  try:
    f2()
  except ValueError:
    # handle error exactly the same as in 1
else:
  raise ValueError
```

Since the error handling in my first two clauses is exactly the same, I'd like to refactor it, e.g. by moving the try except clause to surround the if/else statement.
However, the else clause also raises a value error, which I don't want to catch since it is caused by bad input. What are my options in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Raise a different error in the `else` block.

```
try:
    if cond1:
        f1()
    elif cond2:
        f2()
    else:
        raise SomeOtherError
except ValueError:
    # handle error
except SomeOtherError
    raise ValueError
```